# Unable to execute /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install... when deploying a Delphi app on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, delphi, xcrun, simctl, rad-studio

I'm trying to set up an environment for releasing iOS apps.

**On my Windows PC** I use RAD Studio 10.2 Update 3 and I created a new Delphi app from one of the samples.

**On my Mac** I have XCode 8.2, iOS 10.0 Simulator, PAServer 19.0 (running).

**In RAD Studio** I override "PLATFORM" environment variable with value "iOSSimulator" (in my HP PC it is used). I defined a connection profile to the Mac and it works. I added iPhoneSimulator 10.2 (it is the only one proposed) to the SDKs.

When I run the application in RAD Studio it **fails** after some time in the deployment phase with this dialog message (I obfuscated the IP):

> Unable to launch process on '123.123.123.123' using the parameters
> from the 'Mac VM di XCodeClub' profile.
>
> The following error was
> returned: 'Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/xcrun" simctl install
> "/Users/xcodeclub/PAServer/scratch-dir/bluish-...VM di
> bluish/MasterDetailApplication.app"' (Error 117)
>
> Usage: `simctl install <device> <path>`
>
> '

What is the problem? A missing file, an incorrect invocation of `simctl`...?

If I change target to OS X (adding the SDK and changing "PLATFORM" to "OSX32") it works.

Comment: first you must use iOS 11 to be able to deploy to the appStore. after it's already a lot of time i don't use the simulator as it's simply don't work (can not use library from the simulator). so better to get the simulator away and use only real device

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same problem yesterday and after extensive trial and errors, I found that the default iOS Simulator installed when installing Xcode was not supported by Delphi, thus generating that error due to missing compatible SDK.

Since I use Delphi 10.3.1 Rio which supports up to iOS 10.3.2, I used Xcode/Components to install just that and voila, all solved.

In your case I suggest you to find out supported versions of iOS Simulator first, or simply choose some older versions and work your way forward :)

Hope I have helped.

Comment: Thank you @TDDung, now I cannot try anymore, but hope your solution could help someone else!